# How to know the SSH key's length and type?

Tags: bash, ssh, key

How to know the SSH key's length and type?
If possible, how can I put them in variables where I can call later?

Answer (score 7):

You should be able to get the details as follows:

```
# check length and type of key
$ key_length=$(ssh-keygen -lf 00.key | awk '{print $1}'); echo $key_length
$ key_type=$(ssh-keygen -lf 00.key | awk '{print $3}'); echo $key_type


$ ssh-keygen -lf 00.key
2048 SHA256:<key_in_base64> no comment (DSA)

$ ssh-keygen -lf 00.key
256 SHA256:<key_in_base64> no comment (ECDSA)

$ ssh-keygen -lf 00.key
2048 SHA256:<key_in_base64> no comment (RSA)

$ ssh-keygen -lf 00.key
00.key is not a public key file.
```

Comment: Thank you, @moirisa, I can see it now.

Comment: BTW, this will work with both private key and public key. Also, the `$3` for key type, might be $4 if it has user@host reference like: `4096 SHA256:GQYs+cJD0cQB5i7uw0ACt6GMOecUXllx4sV5G3zAI70 runner@6c2e8ac9eeac (RSA)`. Maybe it's best to switch that `$3` into a `$NF`.

Comment: @AlexandreJuma, what does the variable acronym `NF` stand for?

Comment: NF is a predefined variable whose value is the number of fields in the current record. awk automatically updates the value of NF each time it reads a record. So when you access $NF, you're actually getting the last tokenized item (i.e: last word, if the separator is whitespace). For "I love cars", NF=3 and $NF=cars.